# hyphenation and punctuation with ".–" at the end of the line

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

I have to edit a text (actually a diary) where the line quite often ends with: .– (point and dash) eg.

"Last night I took the subway.–"

LaTeX does not break the word "subway" if it's at the end of the line.

From this 
[how to get latex to hyphenate a word that contains a dash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193307/how-to-get-latex-to-hyphenate-a-word-that-contains-a-dash) 
i understand that the package hyphenat might be of some help, but I don't understand the manual.

Is there a way to tell LaTeX to regard ".–" just as it would do with ", !, ?, ., ;" etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a command called (say) `\dotdash` defined by

```
\def\dotdash{\nobreak\hspace{0pt}.--}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I have to write {\dotdash} though so that the following space does not get erased, but that's usual TeX-behaviour.

Comment: @MartinMueller If (as seems likely) you always have white space after, you could add a space after the `--` in the definition.

Comment: I know, i was contemplating that and probably it makes more sense than what I added.